# What is the language that this DFA accepts?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I've faced this question in my homework, I tried to solve it but I couldn't.

We're given a DFA:

---

[image: DFA]

---

Every time I tried to define the language, I found a word that the DFA accepts but the language I defined doesn't. I'll be thankful if anyone can at least tell the language the DFA defines without giving any explanation or proof of why it does.

---

One more question that isn't related to the topic: How could I put a text/image in the center of the page? like the image above, how could I put it in the center? I tried using < center > but it couldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It accepts the language $\{w \in \{0,1\}^* \; : \; |w|_0 - |w|_1 \equiv 1 \pmod{3} \}$, where $|w|_x$ denotes the number of occurrences of character $x \in \{0,1\}$ in the word $w$.

To see that this is indeed the case, notice that state $q_i$ encodes the situation in which that the number of $0$s minus the number of $1$s read so far is $i \pmod{3}$.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand exactly your definition, for example, the word $11$ is accepted by the language, and $|w|_0 - |w|_1 = -2$, to here I got it but I don't get the rest. What does the symbol mean $\equiv$ means exactly here and can it be replaced with $=$? Also for more cleareness, can you explain the language in words?

Comment: $x \equiv y \pmod{z}$ means that the remainder of the division of $x$ by $z$ equals the remainder of the division of $y$ by $z$.  See, e.g., the Wikipedia page on [modular artihmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). In your example $11$ is in the language since since  $-2 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$. The language contains all words $w$ such that the difference between the number of occurrences of $0$ and the number of occurrences of $1$ in $w$ is one more than a multiple of $3$, i.e., it is $\dots, -8, -5, -2, 1, 4, 7, \dots$.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot, the answer was verified.